# Can't set pickerView titleForRow as (String?, String?)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uipickerview, ios10

I'm using CoreData and I'm trying to have 2 different columns in my `UIPickerView` with Stores and the Item Type

When I run it, the items are "there" but they appear as a "?"

here is my code for my `titleForRow` function:

```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> (String?, String?) {
    //title
    let store = stores[row]
    let itemType = itemTypes[row]

    // select store out of array of stores
    return (store.name, itemType.type)
}
```

something to note is Xcode is giving me a warning saying:

> Instance method 'pickerVIew(titleForRow:forComponent:)' nearly matches
>   optional requirement 'pickerView(titleForRow:forComponent:)' of
>   protocol UIPickerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return only `String` type, not tuple. If you want to add two columns, you need to set

```
pickerView.numberOfComponents = 2
```

and check `component` parameter like:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return component == 0 ? stores[row].name : itemTypes[row].type
}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a ton